# Is it possible to share pure FP state between multiple http requests on http4s server?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, fs2, http4s

I'm trying to share state between multiple http requests on `http4s` server.

That is what I tried:

```
for {
     state  <- Ref[F].of(0)
 
    _ <- BlazeServerBuilder[F]
         .bindHttp(port, host)
         .withHttpApp( ... httpApp that has link to "state" ... )
         .serve.compile.lastOrError

} yield  ()
```

The state remains the same after I change it inside http request.

Is it possible to share "state" in a pure FP style using `Ref` or something from `Fs2`?

**UPDATE**: the problem was inside my app. not related to how I pass the Ref. my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify state just fine inside an HTTP request. Side effects are the whole point of the IO monad, and mutable state is what `Ref` is for. Here's an example of a route that will count the number of times it has been called:

```scala
  def countRoutes[F[_]: Defer: Monad](ref: Ref[F, Int]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
    val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F]{}
    import dsl._
    HttpRoutes.of[F] {
      case GET -> Root / "count" =>
        for {
          current  <- ref.updateAndGet(_ + 1)
          resp <- Ok(current.toString)
        } yield resp
    }
  }
```

Your initialization code looks weird though. It should be something like this:

```scala
for {
    state  <- Ref[IO].of(0)
    exitCode <- BlazeServerBuilder[F]
           .bindHttp(port, host)
           .withHttpApp( ... httpApp that has link to "state" ... )
           .serve.compile.lastOrError
} yield exitCode
```

Comment: I faced almost the same problem. Is it possible to use `Ref` in case each request allocates some `Resource` which are then combined together to get freed? I mean something like `Ref[F, Resource[F, Unit]]`